# Is it possible to bind a XAML control to a corresponding control in the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am using WPF with the intent of adhering to the MVVM model. I have multiple controls in my XAML view, such as buttons, combo boxes, etc, and I have a corresponding set of controls in my ViewModel. Is there a way to bind a control (such as a button, for example) in XAML to a matching control in the ViewModel, so they have a one-to-one relationship?

I am aware of how it is usually done, with specific XAML control properties being bound to specific properties within the ViewModel. I thought that by binding an entire control to a matching control, it would simplify the binding process. I wouldn't need to bind individual properties, I could just bind the entire control and then programmatically modify any properties I wanted to in the ViewModel.

For example, my XAML button control would look something like this (the DataBinding property is not an actual property):

```
<Button DataBinding="SignInButton" />
```

And all the properties for the button would not be set in XAML, but rather in my ViewModel:

```
public Button SignInButton;
SignInButton.Content = "Sign In";
SignInButton.Width = 100;
SignInButton.FontFamily = "Verdana";
```

Comment: I guess the act of me actually having a "Button" object in the ViewModel is what causes it to not adhere to MVVM, right? That should be kept in the View alone?

Comment: Instead of having your `Control` which is clearly a `View`s element in your `ViewModel` nothing to do with view, i.e. ViewModel should never be aware of `View`. Have an inner class with defined button specific elements and then bind them to the button. If you don't want to bind properties to the `ViewModel` consider using Blend and then define properties you want to bind otherwise you can't just bind a `Control` without specifying the properties. At least I am not aware of such way, without breaking `MvvM`. HTH

Comment: Makes sense. Having the Control itself in my ViewModel would be breaking the MVVM pattern. I will stick with just binding individual properties when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the controls in ViewModel as ContentControl Properties and Bind them in XAML.